# Nav bar is showing up overlapped with bullet points and 'HiOutlineMenuAlt4' icon is not appearing either

Tags: reactjs

My nav bar is showing up overlapped with bullet points and 'HiOutlineMenuAlt4' icon is not appearing either. I am not sure what to do, I can't identify where the issue actually lies? Is it in the css?

Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {BiSearch} from 'react-icons/bi'
import {BsPerson} from 'react-icons/bs'
import {HiOutlineMenuAlt4} from 'react-icons/hi'

import './NavbarStyles.css'

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
        <div className='logo'>
            <h2>BEACHES. </h2>
        </div>

        <ul className='nav-menu'>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Destinations</li>
            <li>Travel</li>
            <li>Book</li>
            <li>Views</li>
        </ul>

      <div className='nav-icons'>
        <BiSearch className='icon'/>
        <BsPerson className='icon'/>
      </div>

      <div className='hamburger'>
        < className='icon' />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

NavbarStyles.css

```
.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    z-index: 2;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
}

.hamburger{
    display: none;
   padding: 1rem;

}
```

No problems are listed so hard to decipher what to do next

Comment: [Steph G ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20768571/steph-g) just add this to your css file. `.nav-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
} ` Also you forgot to put HiOutlineMenuAlt4 in its tag. You are doing `< className='icon' />` as opposed to `<HiOutlineMenuAlt4 className='icon' />`

Comment: @Steph G, if down below code is not satisfying your question. Then, consider for adding more details about your code.

Answer (score 0):

###### Hi @Steph G,

About your icons `HiOutlineMenuAlt4`.

You are not using the imported `HiOutlineMenuAlt4` icon in the hamburger div

```js
<div className='hamburger'>
  <HiOutlineMenuAlt4 className='icon' />
</div>
```

And about your **CSS,** that code is enough.

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```